# Multiple inputboxes one test for null input

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so I have a series of input boxes pop up for the user and I know I want to check if the user hits cancel or "X" then I will have to check its return value.

EX answer = inputbox("lelele")  if answer = "" then end else  end if.

My problem is I have 4 input boxes in a row and I don't want to have to do a separate  if statement for every input box so is there a way I can check all three in some sort of try catch block or while loop?

Below is the code I am actually using. Keep in mind that I am trying to catch a cancel every step along the way, so any time anyone clicks cancel the program immediately stops running.

```
'column you want to first select for copying
ColSelect = InputBox("which column do you want to select ColCopyFrom") 
'the column you are comparing it to
ColCompare = InputBox("which column do you want to compare to ") 
'where you are copying data from
ColCopyFrom = InputBox("which column do you want to copy data ColCopyFrom") 
'where you are copying data to
ColCopyTo = InputBox("which column do you want to copy data to")
```

<

This is what I want to do for every box

```
if ColSelect = "" then
  exit
else
'do nothing
end if

if ColCompare = "" then
  exit
else

end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the inputbox into a function passing the prompt as a parameter like this and use END to break:

```
Function myInputBox(prompt As String) As String
    Dim ib As String
    ib = InputBox(prompt)

    If ...
    '... do some checking here
    Else
        End 'stop dead here
    End if


    myInputBox = ib
End Function
```

On the other hand, you might think about using a [UserForm](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html) instead for enhanced usability.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a function and call it to check for each input? By creating a function once you can call upon it as many times as necessary, in your case 4 times. When you call the function you can then substitute the variable to check against

```
'first inputbox
Call checker(ColSelect)

'second input box
Call checker(ColCompare)

'etc
```

This is the function to check and you will see the variable name is cancel. This will take the variable entered (in the example ColSelect) and then give it a new name. This can be anything you like

```
sub checker(cancel)

    if cancel = "" then
        exit
    else
        'do nothing
    end if

end Sub
```